# iOS - not displayed correctly inline-blocks

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

Have a site http://nt-work3.bl.ee/about.html

For windows users its all ok.
Fot iOS users there are problems:

Main menu item has a class .current-menu-item that turns background color to white. For windows users everything is fine.. But fot iOS users there is a pink line on the top and bottom 1px, please, see the screenshot [SCREEN](http://joxi.ru/YkOoU_3JTJBxWRYm3s0) I thought it was a basic indentation inline-blocks, and I add font-size:0; line-height:0; for ul. But it dont help..

Please help to solve these problems who have an iOS gadget..

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has some useful mobile emulation stuff, try emulating a mobile device and see if you can't debug your CSS (i'd assume that's what the problem is): https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/mobile-emulation

Comment: it emulate correctly only resolution, there are no problems on emulation which is in iOS. Sorry for my english.

Comment: oh, i understand now. I'm seeing it on my simulator but I haven't figured it out yet. I'll try again later once work is over.